# How to create an alias for a color in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am importing a bunch of color-tokens from our designsystem. I want to give an alias to one of these colors so that I can easily change the color of all the elements that use this alias.

Here is what I'm trying to do in my tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  important: '#root',
  theme: {
    colors: {
      ...myColors, //From design system
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // This doesn't work :(
        customColor: 'primary-50', //primary-50 is a token that comes from the designsystem import.
      },
...
```

After doing something like this I was thinking that I could use the color like so on my elements:

```
<div className="bg-customColor">My element</div>
//instead of this:
<div className="bg-primary-50">My element</div>
```

Is there any way to do something like this? Or do I have to create a special class in my `index.css` that I'll have to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Tailwind creates a bunch of css-variables which you can reference instead of the tailwind-token:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  important: '#root',
  theme: {
    colors: {
      ...myColors, //From design system
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // This works! :)
        customColor: 'var(--color-primary-50)',
      },
...
```

Comment: Could you reference some documentation for this? Because it does not seem to work for me.